# Java program to read Strings from console and print the String with maximum number of words in it

Tags: java, string, collections, linked-list, hashmap

I am trying to solve a programming puzzle. Here, user is expected to read n number of Strings from console and print the string that has maximum number of words in it.

I am getting casting issues when I am trying to convert List to HashMap

The error is:

```
prog.java:33: error: incompatible types: HashMap<String,Integer> cannot be converted to Entry<String,Integer>
Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry = (HashMap<String,Integer> ) printResult.entrySet();
```

My code is as followed:

```
import java.io.*;

import java.util.*;

import java.util.LinkedList; 


class GFG {


public static void main (String[] args) {

    int i=0,counter=0;
    String[] strArray= new String[10];
    Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);
    HashMap<String, Integer> hm = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    while(sn.nextLine()!=null)
    {
        strArray[i]=sn.nextLine();
        String temp=strArray[i];
        int j=0;
        while(j<temp.length())
        {
            if(temp.charAt(j)==' ')
            {
                counter++;
            }
            j++;
        }
       hm.put(temp,counter); 
       i++;
    }
    GFG g1=new GFG();
    HashMap<String, Integer> printResult = g1.sortByValue(hm);
    Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry = (HashMap<String,Integer> ) printResult.entrySet();
    System.out.println(entry.getKey());
}
    public HashMap<String, Integer> sortByValue(HashMap<String, Integer> hm) 
    { 
    // Create a list from elements of HashMap 
    List<Map.Entry<String, Integer> > list = 
           new LinkedList<Map.Entry<String, Integer> >(hm.entrySet()); 

    // Sort the list 
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer> >() { 
        public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Integer> o1,  
                           Map.Entry<String, Integer> o2) 
        { 
            return (o1.getValue()).compareTo(o2.getValue()); 
        } 
    }); 


    Map<String,Integer> printResult = (HashMap<String, Integer>) list.getLast();
    System.out.println(printResult);
    return printResult;

    } 
}
```

Comment: Your `entrySet()` returns a `Set<Map.Entry<String,Integer>>` .

Comment: what problem do you get, and why do you try to convert it into a hashmap?

Comment: As it stands, you application doesn't even get to the crucial part

Comment: @Stultuske
I am practicing Map implementation. Hence, the implementation using Map.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer:
Would appreciate your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code has many problems.  Rather than trying to salvage your current approach, I recommend keeping track of the running longest string as you go along:

```
int longest = 0;
String str;
String next = sn.nextLine();

while (!"END".equals(next)) {
    int length = next.split("\\s+").length;
    if (length > longest) {
        longest = length;
        str = next;
    }

    // enter END to end the loop/program
    next = sn.nextLine();
}

System.out.println("longest string: " + str);
System.out.println("has " + longest + " words");
```

Comment: Hi,

I am practicing collections concept and wanted to implement this logic using Maps only. Could you please advice me on the same implementation?

Answer (score 0):

> (HashMap ) printResult.entrySet()

Here you try to Cast an EntrySet to a Hashmap, this does not work. Just remove your cast and replace your Left Hand Side Type of

```
Map.Entry<String,Integer>
```

with

```
Set<Map.Entry<String,Integer>>
```

Comment: Not Working. Errors as followed:
error: cannot find symbol
  Set<Map.Entry<String,Integer>> entry = (Set<Map.Entry<String,Integer>>)printResult.entrySet();
symbol:   method entrySet()
prog.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
  System.out.println(entry.getKey());
                          ^
  symbol:   method getKey()
etc..,